# The fundamental theorem of Galois theory

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $E/Q$ be a Galois extension of degree $p^2$,  where $p$ is a prime number. Prove that $L/Q$ is a Galois extension for any $L \in Intermediate(E/Q)$ and find $p$ if the cardinality of $Intermediate(E/Q)$ is 100.

I'm trying to apply The fundamental theorem of Galois theory but not sure where to start.

Comment: What's the group-theoretic condition on an intermediate extension $L/Q$ of $E/Q$ that ensures $L/Q$ is Galois (group-theoretic in reference to the corresponding subgroup $\mathrm{Gal}(L/E)\subseteq\mathrm{Gal}(L/Q)$)?

Comment: @KeenanKidwell So you mean finite p-subgroup? Since the degree is $p^2$, we can have a chain of groups then use the fundamental theorem of Galois theory?

Comment: Your Galois group $\mathrm{Gal}(L/Q)$ has order $p^2$. A proper, non-trivial subgroup of such a group is of order $p$. What can you say about subgroups of index $p$ in a group of order $p^2$?

Comment: Recall that every group of order $p^2$ is abelian, and all subgroups of abelian groups are normal.

Comment: Does the set Intermediate$(E/\Bbb{Q})$ contain both $E$ and $\Bbb{Q}$ as well? Because the word *intermediate* appears there I would suspect that it does not. But, unless it does, there is no such $p$?

Answer (score 0):

Note the following segment from the fundamental theorem of galois theory

Let $L$ be an intermediate field of $E/Q$, then $L/Q$ is galois $\iff Gal(E/L)\trianglelefteq Gal(E/Q)$

That is, $L/Q$ is a galois extension when the galois group for $E/L$ is a normal subgroup of the galois group for $E/Q$. Since $E/Q$ is galois, $|Gal(E/Q)|=[E:Q]=p^2$. Any group with order $p^2$, where $p$ is prime, is abelian(a proof is provided [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/212084/group-with-order-p2-must-be-abelian-how-to-prove-that)) and as $Gal(E/Q)$ is abelian, all of its subgroups, must be normal subgroups(a proof for this is provided [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_of_Abelian_Group_is_Normal) if you're interested).

As $Q\subseteq L\subseteq E$, $Gal(E/Q)\subseteq Gal(E/Q)$, therefore $Gal(E/L)$ must be a normal subgroup of $Gal(E/Q)$, and by segment from the fundamental theorem of Galois theory, $L/Q$ is a galois extension.