# Prove that a group of order $p^2$ where $p$ is prime is Abelian.

Tags: group-theory

I have to prove the statement in the title. As a lengthy hint the following is given:

> Hint: let $a \in G$ $\not= e$. Suppose $a$ has period $p$ (for period
>   $p^2$ the answer is trivial), then consider the subgroup $H = <a>$.
>   Prove $b \notin H$ implies $G = <a, b>$. Is $H$ normal? Prove $a$ and
>   $b$ commute and conclude $G$ is abelian.

Getting to the point where I prove that $G = <a,b>$ is no problem. However, I don't see on how to proceed to prove that $H$ is normal and assuming that, that $a$ and $b$ commute. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/212084/group-with-order-p2-must-be-abelian-how-to-prove-that   duplicate?

Comment: Assuming you've gotten to the point you claim to have reached: in order to prove that $H$ is normal, it suffices to show $bH = Hb$