# Can you show example a group of order $p^2$ besides $Z_{p^2} $ and $Z_p \oplus Z_p$?

Tags: group-theory

I want to find example a group of order $p^2$ (p is prime) besides $Z_{p^2} $ (group of integer under addition modulo $p^2$) , and $Z_p \oplus Z_p$ (external direct product of groups of integer under addition modulo p)

Comment: Note:  the critical observation is that all such groups are abelian.  you can find proofs of that, e.g., [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/212084/group-with-order-p2-must-be-abelian-how-to-prove-that)

Comment: Thanks for the idea. It is useful for me