# Is the abelian nature of a group preserved under an isomorphism? Can we say the same thing for non-abelian groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism, infinite-groups

How can we show the above assertion if in case it is true (namely that if a group $G$ is abelian and $f:G \to H$ is an isomorphism then $H$ is abelian also)? In particular every group is isomorphic to a finite group (by Cayley's Theorem). If the group $G$ is finite with order $n$ then it is isomorphic to $S_n$. But $S_n$ is not abelian for $n>3$. What can we then conclude about the group $G$? In particular, is G abelian or not?

Comment: (1) Not every group is isomorphic to a finite group. (2) A group of order $n$ is isomorphic to *a subgroup of* $S_n$. You should make sure you understand the meaning of "isomorphic."

Answer (score 7):

You are misstating Cayley's theorem. It says that if $|G|=n$, then $G$ is isomorphic to a **subgroup** of $S_n$.

Now, when $\phi:G\to H$ is a homomorphism and $G$ is abelian, it follows that for $a,b\in G$,
$$\phi(a)\phi(b)=\phi(ab)=\phi(ba)=\phi(b)\phi(a)$$
so $\phi(G)$ is an abelian subgroup of $H$. For example, the cyclic group $C_n$ embeds as the cyclic subgroup of $S_n$ generated by $(1\,2\,\ldots\,n)$.

I don't know what you are wanting to say about non-abelian groups.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question in the title:

- Homomorphism images of abelian groups are always abelian.
- Non abelian groups can have abelian homomorphic images: $G/G'$ is abelian, where $G'$ is the [commutator or derived subgroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_subgroup).

Comment: Maybe you should explain what the notation $G\color{red}{'}$ denotes.

Comment: @Bernard, done, thanks for the nudge.

Answer (score 1):

Given a group $G$ of order $n$ you cannot decide in general whether or not $G$ is abelian. You need to know more about the group. For example, given a group of order $6$, this group may be abelian or may not be abelian. Both cases occur, namely $G=S_3$ and $G=C_6$.

In some special cases, however, you can "conclude". One case would be, that $n=p$ or $n=p^2$ with $p$ prime. Any group of that order must be abelian - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253922/prove-that-any-group-g-of-order-p2-is-abelian-where-p-is-a-prime-number).

A remark to your claim that any group $G$ of order $n$ must be isomorphic to $S_n$. This cannot be true because already the orders are different for $n\ge 3$.