# classify groups of order $p^2$ simple or not

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

I wonder $p$-groups of order $p^2$ simple or not. I know all of them are abelian. So center equal whole group.Hence, it is not useful to test simplicity.

> - How we can classify them according to whether they are simple or not. For example;

Let $G$ be a group such that $|G|=25=5^2$. Then $G$ has Sylow $5$-subgroup(s) order $25$ such that  $n_5\equiv 1$ (mod  $5)$.

> - I could not imagine how I would continue i.e., is it simple or not ?

Comment: This can be generalized to the fact that there are no simple groups of order $p^{n}$ where $n \ge 2$. I suggest you prove this by considering the group action of the group $G$ on the set of subsets(note, not subgroup) of $G$ which are of cardinality $p^{n-1}$.

Comment: Do you maybe mean "there are no non-abelian simple groups of order less than $60$?"

Comment: @lulu I dont mean it. If you click to link then you can see this: If $G=p^n$ for a prime number $p$ and a natural number $n$, then $Z(G)$ is nontrivial. To me, it is not useful argument for  groups of order $p^2$. Because group is abelian. Actullay, this argument is not useful for all abelian group.

Comment: @S.C.B. Thank you. But I am not familiar with group action. You mean conjugate action on set.

Comment: Not following. Obviously there are non-abelian groups of order less than $60$ so, as stated, your example is wrong.  Please correct it.

Comment: @1Spectre1 I'm not talking about that, unfortunately.

Comment: @1Spectre1 Actually this is better. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64371/showing-non-cyclic-group-with-p2-elements-is-abelian

Comment: @lulu, I edited my question. I need  easy argument.

Comment: No group of order $p^2$ is simple.  There is always a subgroup of order $p$.

Comment: How can you say this fact? $p|p^2$. Then, $G$ has any element of $a$ such that $|a|=p$ due to Cauchy theorem. Then $\langle a\rangle$ is normal subgroup because of  commutativity.

Comment: @S.C.B. I understand your comment:there are no simple groups of order  $p^n$ where $n\geq 2$. If group non-abelian then center is non-trivial proper normal subgroup. If group abelian then there exist any element of $a$ order $p$( Cauchy Theorem). Then $\langle a\rangle$ must be proper normal subgroup order $p$ because group is abelian. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The abelian groups of order $p^2$ are $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} $ and both are not simple.

Comment: why $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is not simple?

Comment: It has a normal subgroup $\mathbb {Z} /p\mathbb {Z} \times {1} $

Answer (score 0):

Note that if p is the smallest prime dividing the order of G, then any subgroup of index p is normal, and since group of prime power order have subgroup of index p, hence they can not be simple.