# If ${\rm order}(G) = p^2 $, where $p$ is prime number , then $G$ is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

I  found the  Proof  Here [Showing group with $p^2$ elements is Abelian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64371/showing-group-with-p2-elements-is-abelian) , But here some  proof are complicated  , those who are beginner in algebra will difficult  them to  understand

> Theorem : If ${\rm order}(G) = |G|= p^2 $, where $p$ is prime number, then $G$ is abelian.

My attempt : Possible  of $|Z(G)|$ are $1 , p , p^2$

## Step $1:$

We must know  one  theorem for this proof , that is  if $order (G) =p^n $, where $p$  is prime  number , then $Z(G) \neq (e) $or u  can say that $ order(Z(G)) > 1$

Proof :  We  know  that class  equation of $G$ is

$|G| =  \sum_{N(a) = |G|} \frac{|G|}{|N(a)|} + \sum_{N(a) \neq |G|} \frac{|G|}{|N(a)|}= |Z(G)| + \sum_{a \notin Z(G)} \frac{|G|}{|N(a)|} $

by Lagrange's Theorem ,$|N(a)|$ divide $|G|$ for each $a \notin Z$, Now take $|N(a) |=p^k$ where $0 < k <n$ , we will get $\frac{|G|}{|N(a)|}= p^{n-k}$

$p$ divide $\frac{|G|}{|N(a)|}$ whenever $a \notin  Z(G)$ that implies
$p$ divide $\sum_{a \notin Z(G)} \frac{|G|}{|N(a)|} .$

We also know that $|G|= p^n$ so  $p$ will divide $|G| -\sum_{a \notin Z(G)} \frac{|G|}{|N(a)|} $---(from class equation $G$)

So  $p$ will divide  $|Z(G)|$

from the above modulo $p$, we have that $|Z(G)|\equiv 0\pmod{p}$, when $|Z(G)|>1$.

So Now  theorem is proof, and $|Z(G)|= 1$ is rejected.

## Step $ 2:$

Let $|Z(G)|= p^2$, then $|G|= |Z(G)| $ implies $G=Z(G)$ since  $Z(G)$ is  subgroup  of $ G$.This  show  the  behaviour of abelian Group  because  for  any  $a \in G $ implies $ a \in Z(G)$ that will hit $ax= xa$ for all  $x, a  \in G$
so ,$|G| = p^2$ is abelian.

So $|Z(G)|= p^2$ is  accepted.

## Step $3$:

Let $|Z(G)| = p $, we know  that $Z(G)$  is a proper subgroup  of $G$   so  that  there  exist   some  $a  \in G $ such that $a \notin Z(G)$.

We also know that $N(a) = \{ x \in G : xa = ax \}$ is  a subgroup  of $G$ .  we  also know  that $Z(G) \subset N(a)$ because $Z(G) = \{x \in G : gx = xg \textrm{ } \forall g \in G \}$. Hence, if $x \in Z(G)$ then $xa = ax$ i.e. $x \in N(a)$.

Here  we already said in first sentence  that  $a \notin Z(G)$ , so  $a \in N(a)$.

By lagrange theorem , we  have $|N(a)|$ divide $|G|$ .Its  show that $|N(a)|$ must  be greater than $p$ because  $|G|= p^2$.

Consequently $|N(a)| = p^2$  implies $|N(a)|=|G|$ so $N(a)= G$  because $ N(a)$ is  a  subgroup  of $G$. Now   $x \in N(a)$  for  all $x  \in G$ its  implies $ax = xa$ for  all $ x\in G $.

Now from Step $:2$, it show  that   $a \in Z(G)$ which  is contradiction  because  $a \notin Z(G) $ (read the first sentence again).

So $|Z(G)|= p$ is  rejected.

## Any  suggestion  for  improving  this proof is sufficient.

Comment: Looks fine but can be tidied up a bit.  Step 2 feels out of order since it is your conclusion, so it’s better left to the end.  In Step 3 you never explicitly state that $N(a) \ne Z(G)$, even though you justify this by pointing out $a$ belongs to one and not the other.  This is at the heart of your argument so it deserves to be made clear.  Minor problem in Step 1: the class equation sums over conjugacy classes but your summation index suggests summing over all elements outside of the center.

Comment: @ErickWong thanks u for  pointing  out mistake

Comment: In general, $N(S)$ is the **normalizer** of the subgroup generated by $S$. You should use $C(a)$, the centralizer of $a$, for the subgroup you are dealing with.

Comment: In step 3, it is an easy exercise to show that if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ is Abelian. This can shorten this step. Note that if $a$ is a generator for this factor group, then each $g \in G$ can be written as $$g=a^nh$$ for some $n$ and $h \in Z(G)$, and $g$'s of this type commute.

Comment: @N.S.  i thinks  according to  ur  statement   , then $|Z(G)|= p $ will also accepted   and that   will  contradicts my  step 3  which  i  have said  that  $ |Z(G)|=p$ is  rejected

Comment: @jasmine If $|Z(G)|=p$ then $|G/Z(G)|=p$ so this is cyclic. Then, by the above $G$ is abelian. But this means $G=Z(G)$ and hence $|Z(G)|=p^2$. In other words you prove that if $|Z(G)|=p$ then $|Z(G)|=p^2$, meaning it is not acceptable.

Comment: @N.S. thanks u now got ur logics ..